# In Golang which type should I use for a method-only type?

Tags: oop, go

I mean a method-only type like this

```
var Util util
type util struct { }
func (util)Help(v VM) {}
func (util)HelpMe(v VM) {}
func (util)HelpYou(v VM) {}
func (util)HelpEveryOne(v VM) {}
```

I see this in [binary.BigEndian](http://golang.org/src/encoding/binary/binary.go)

```
// LittleEndian is the little-endian implementation of ByteOrder.
var LittleEndian littleEndian

// BigEndian is the big-endian implementation of ByteOrder.
var BigEndian bigEndian

type littleEndian struct{}
```

This is a very tricky way to group your method. So the question is: why `struct{}`?  Why not just a `int` alias, is there any reason to choose `struct{}` over other types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that the main difference between `struct {}` and `int` is that `struct {}` takes up no memory whereas an unused `int` would waste 4 or 8 bytes.